# jQuery animation keeping auto positioning with div resize

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-animate, margin

I have a leftmenu div that can be shown and hidden on click. A content div on the right that is aligned margin:0 auto; When i resize the window it perfectly aligns in the middle of the window. But, what i want is that when the left menu div animates to its full width, the content div should animate to the center of the remaining space left on the right size. Irrespective of screen resolution.

Someone has an idea how to accomplish this? My guess is to calculate something like:

document.viewport - leftmenu.width and then the remaining space half aligned to the center of the content div.

aargh have a blackout . anyone?

here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5A3qA/48/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#content').css('position','absolute');
var nwpos =  ( $(window).width() - $('#content').width() ) / 2;        
nwpos= nwpos+ (tcontainer.width()/2);
$('#content').css("left", nwpos + "px");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you'll have to calculate the width of current windows and subtract the amount of width the left menu is taking. Then from the remaining width, get the center i.e. width/2 and subtract half of the width of your content width from it.

w = Screen Width - Width of Left Menu
left = w/2 - contentdivWidth /2 
contentwidth.left = left